# Android Capture user latitude and longitude and save to sqlite database

Tags: java, android, geolocation, android-sqlite, locationmanager

In my activity I want to capture user's latitude and longitude and save it to the database. User's latitude and longitude is captured when checked with a debugger but it is not inserting in the database. It is saved as null in database. When user clicks save button saveData() is called and values should insert in db, other values except latitude and longitude are inserting.  The fields declared are  PHARMACY_LATITUDE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
PHARMACY_LONGITUDE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +How do I fix this? Please provide a solution.

```
public class ParentFragmentChemist extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
LocationListener locationListener;
LocationManager locationManager;
Double pharmacy_lat,pharmacy_lon;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_parent_fragment_chemist);
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
            pharmacy_lat = location.getLatitude();
            pharmacy_lon = location.getLongitude();
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            System.out.println("pharmacy_lat "+pharmacy_lat + "pharmacy_lon" +pharmacy_lon);
           
        }
    };
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},101);
    }else{
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);

    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if((requestCode == 101) && (grantResults.length > 0)){
        if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);

            }

        }
    }

}
saveData(){
pcount = pcount + 1;
                    String where = Queryclass.DAYACTIVITY_DATE_ID + " = " + id;
                    ContentValues cvphcount = new ContentValues();
                    cvphcount.put(Queryclass.DAYACTIVITY_DCR, "1");
                    cvphcount.put(Queryclass.DAYACTIVITY_PHARMACYCOUNT, Integer.toString(pcount));
                    sd.update(Queryclass.TABLE_DAYACTIVITY, cvphcount, where);

                    ContentValues cvDoctor = new ContentValues();
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_DATE_ID, id);
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_DCRTYPE, Datafields.dcrtype);
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_CONTACTID, Datafields.contactid);
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_CONTACTNAME, Datafields.contactname);
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_BRICKID, Datafields.pharmacyBrickId);
                    Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
                    String hr = String.valueOf(instance.get(Calendar.HOUR));
                    String mn = String.valueOf(instance.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_VISITTIME, hr+":"+ mn);
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_JOINTWORK, Datafields.jointwork);
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_AVAILABILITY, Datafields.availability);
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_POB, Datafields.pob);
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_NOUNITS, Datafields.nou);
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_CALLTYPE, Datafields.chemistCallTypeData);
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_CAMPAIGNCALL, Datafields.chemistCampaignCallData);
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_RCPA, Datafields.RCPA_DATA);
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_REMARKS, Datafields.Customer_remark);
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_DATE_TIME, CommonUtils.getDateTimeStamp(dateTimeStampFormat));
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_LATITUDE, pharmacy_lat);
                    cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_LONGITUDE, pharmacy_lon);
                    boolean result=sd.isExist(Queryclass.TABLE_PHARMA,id,CommonUtils.getDateTimeStamp(dateTesting),Queryclass.PHARMACY_DATE_TIME,Queryclass.PHARMACY_CONTACTID,Queryclass.PHARMACY_DATE_ID);
                    if(result){

                    }else{
                        sd.insert(Queryclass.TABLE_PHARMA, cvDoctor);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only possible issue here would be that before the **pharmacy_lat** and **pharmacy_lon** is being fetched the **saveData()** function is called.

Since you have not initilized the values of **pharmacy_lon** & **pharmacy_lat** and they are not fetched also thus in Database they are saved as **null**.

To fix this issue you can do below things:

```
//Need to initialise these 2 variables otherwise it in Db they will be stored as null
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Double pharmacy_lat = 0
     Double pharmacy_lon = 0
}


saveData(){
   if( pharmacy_lat <= 0 || pharmacy_lon <= 0){
      Toast.makeToast("TAG", "The location is not fetched yet", Toast.SHORT);
      return;
   }

   //Else do the same logic you were doing previously.

}
```

In the above code we will make sure that fetching part is completed and **pharmacy_lat** and **pharmacy_lon** actually have some values which is greater than 0.

Hope this will resolve your query and Keep Coding...

Comment: Its not working ..App is crashing android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: pharmacy_latitude (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: UPDATE pharmacy SET pharmacy_jointwork=?,pharmacy_date_time=?,pharmacy_latitude=?,pharmacy_longitude=?,pharmacy_campaigncall=?,phar

Comment: @Abm please check your SQLITE table structure if you have this key or not there. Also there could be a spelling mismatch in KEYS for ** pharmacy_latitude** in Table and Query. This exception is not relate to location it is related to your Table structure. Can you share your table structure here?

Comment: -   public static String CREATE_PHARMACY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PHARMA + " (" +
            PHARMACY_ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            PHARMACY_DATE_ID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            PHARMACY_DCRTYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            PHARMACY_REMARKS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            PHARMACY_LATITUDE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            PHARMACY_LONGITUDE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            "FOREIGN KEY(" + PHARMACY_DATE_ID + ") REFERENCES day_Activity(date_id) ON DELETE CASCADE" + ");";

Answer (score 0):

While creating the table TABLE_PHARMA, you have declared PHARMACY_LATITUDE and PHARMACY_LONGITUDE as TEXT type. But while inserting into the table, you are inserting a double datatype value.

```
cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_LATITUDE, pharmacy_lat);
cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_LONGITUDE, pharmacy_lon);
```

First convert them into String datatype and then insert it, it will work.

```
cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_LATITUDE, String.valueOf(pharmacy_lat));
cvDoctor.put(Queryclass.PHARMACY_LONGITUDE, String.valueOf(pharmacy_lon));
```